# Using the fade function in less for CSS

Tags: less

I am using Mindscape workbench and .dotless. When I code the following it works good:

```
@base: #f04615;

#logo {
  color: saturate(@base, 5%);
  background-color: darken(@base, 10%);
}

gives me:

#logo {
    background-color: #C5360D;
}
```

However the following gives nothing and it seems like Mindscape does not even recognize fade:

```
#logo {
  background-color: fade(@base, 10%);
}
```

Has anyone else had some similar problems?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mindscape, but you might want to see what version of LESS it is using. I compiled your code using the latest CodeKit and got what you would expect: #logo {
  background-color: rgba(240, 70, 21, 0.1); } Maybe see if there is an issue with Mindscape supporting rgb(a)?

Comment: We currently support the latest version of LESS, I think Samantha needs to grab our latest update from the Visual Studio Gallery or Extension Manager :-)

Comment: I used `rgba(red(@base),green(@base),blue(@base),.1)`

Comment: fade is just for the 50%, if you want to have a opacity, you have to use fadeout(@color, percent of 100% - your number of opacity)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the version of less mindscape is following does not support the colour fade() functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check you're using the latest version of the Web Workbench? In my version (latest version on the Visual Studio Gallery) this compiles perfectly to:

```
#logo {
  background-color: rgba(240, 70, 21, 0.1);
}
```

We typically ship an update a few days after each new release of LESS (or Sass, or CoffeeScript comilers). Inside Visual Studio go to Tools -> Extension Manager and then check the "Updates" tab. It can take a few moments to check for updates so give it a moment.

If you still have problems after updating please let me know or post on our forum and we can help get you sorted.

I hope that helps.